# Cannot create a dungeon defenders game

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Whenever I try to create a match on Dungeon Defenders it always comes up saying failed to create a game session or something similar to that. Will the problem stop at some point? I can join other games perfectly, but I cannot create one. This has happened at 2 different houses and I have un/reinstalled the game but no change, is it my laptop?

-TCP does not work and I have uninstalled Hamachi which I though would have solved the problem, but it did not.

This problem has been happening for the past 5 days.

Comment: Fixed the problem, AVG was blocking it somehow.

Comment: Since you resolved it, you can post an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVG was blocking me from hosting or joining a game. To stop this I had to disable AVG. To disable AVG you:

1)Open the AVG interface

2)Open the options from the drop-down menu from the top right of the interface

3)Click advanced settings (around the middle of the menu)

4)Click Temporarily Disable AVG Protection

5)Disable until next restart

6)You can now play Dungeon Defenders